# OpenfireHome - Home not found

Tags: openfire

I have xmpp server (openfire_3.9.3) that is running on my ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

I have installed openfire by following given steps

```
1. $ sudo tar -zxvf openfire_x_x_x.tar.gz
2. $ sudo mv openfire /opt
```

then I moved to openfire bin directory to start openfire as

```
$ cd /opt/openfire/bin

$ sudo ./openfire start
```

then during setup through admin console always I am getting the given error

```
Home not found. Define system property "openfireHome" or create and add the openfire_init.xml file to the classpath
```

where I need to set openfireHome ? or how can i fixed it out ?

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems your user account might have permissions issue. Can't you keep openfire in your home and try to run it from there and share results?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's a permissions issue.

I'm using server(Openfire 4.7.0, build e020f58) on my local computer (macOS Monterey 12.1 (21C52)).

My SOLUTION is:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/openfire`